# AtTask is not retrieving all objects

Tags: c#, object, attask

I am trying to retrieve objects from the AtTask API, but only some of them are being retrieved. 
The seven objects I need are as follows (with each result on the right; if "ok", they are giving results correctly):

- **projectName** - ok
- **ID** - ok
- **refreshDate** - blank
- **referenceNumber** - all return 0
- **actualCompletionDate** - all return 1/1/0001 12:00:00 am
- **portfolioID** - blank
- **status** - ok

My code:

```
JToken projects = client.Search(ObjCode.PROJECT, new { groupID = userGroupID, __LIMIT = 2000 });
foreach (var j in projects["data"].Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Project Name: {0}", j.Value<string>("name"));
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", j.Value<string>("ID"));
    Console.WriteLine("Refresh date: {0}", j.Value<string>("refreshDate"));
    Console.WriteLine("Reference number: {0}", j.Value<int>("referenceNumber"));
    Console.WriteLine("Actual completion date: {0}", j.Value<DateTime>("actualCompletionDate"));
    Console.WriteLine("Portfolio ID: {0}", j.Value<string>("portfolioID"));
    Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", j.Value<string>("status"));
}
```

Each API key and field type are named according to https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/api-explorer/.

Why aren't refreshDate, referenceNumber, actualCompletionDate, and portfolioID returning correct values, while the other three are?

Comment: Are you sure they are not returning correct values? What should the values be?

Comment: For one, most of the projects I'm retrieving data for have already been completed. With that in mind, you would think actualCompletionDate would be something other than 1/1/0001... Moreover, my company has been using all of these objects from AtTask before now, but they were retrieved a different way. I am now writing this program to replace what they were doing previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify fields in your search otherwise it will not pull all but the default information.

so this should work

```
JToken projects = client.Search(ObjCode.PROJECT, new { groupID = userGroupID, __LIMIT = 2000 , fields = "name,ID,refreshDate,referenceNumber,actualCompletionDate,portfolioID,status"});
```

Comment: When trying this, it gave me this exception: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Fixed it, I just needed to remove refreshDate. I don't think that one is actually part of AtTask but I was asked to include it. Thank you!